# SQL Connection failure

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sql-server, azure

A common question, I know; my particular circumstances: I have a solution developed in C# in Visual Studio connecting to an Azure SQL Server DB; until now, working fine; basically, for other reasons, I've had to re-create the Server & DB and now I have a connection failure. Relevant points: I can connect OK from VS Connection Manager, which eliminates all basic problems; the error is related to failure to determine SQL Server Version; question: how can I find the real problem? There must be logs somewhere, but I can't find them; any tips on troubleshooting appreciated

Update: I've been misled; the real problem lies elsewhere, but here's what confused me: when you instantiate the connection, it doesn't yet know the SQL Server Version, which it reports, as I mentioned; but the next statement then opens the connection, which actually succeeds; what confused me, is that there was a another problem. Sorry for this. Case closed & thanks for input.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You say that the error is "related to failure to determine SQL Server Version". Can you edit your question to include the complete text of the error message?

Comment: Exact error message: "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_ServerVersion()"

Comment: Further info: I'm using a very similar connection string i.e. with identical parameters to access the same DB from Power BI in an R script, which works fine ...

Comment: That's not the complete error message. That's a portion of the stack trace, telling you the area of code that the error is coming from. But the error message is still missing. Please [edit] the question to include everything that is reported to you in the error message.

Comment: Smells like the [connection isn't getting opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566277/c-sharp-console-application-invalid-operation-exception). Which makes sense, the library can't determine sql server version if it can't connect. Check the firewall rules? What about accepting/trusting the server certificate? Post the relevant connection/command object code?